# ExtJS 3.4 - FormPanel cannot be rendered to <DIV> in Chrome and IE

Tags: extjs3

I am trying to load the jsp content of each tab in tab panel in tabChange listener by calling the .load() method. 
In each jsp, there is a Ext.Panel and rendered to a . I found that if the Ext.Panel contain a Ext.FormPanel or the Ext.FormPanel is directly rendered to the , page will not be shown on the tab and error will be found in IE and Chrome while there is no such problem in Firefox.

The error message in Chrome is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'applyStyles' of null

I have tried to replace the Ext.FormPanel with Ext.Panel, it works, but I must need the Ext.FormPanel for calling .getForm.submit() for SAVE action purpose.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your render a Formpanel inside a Formpanel. So the inner formpanel cannot be rendered in Chrome and IE. But Firefox can ignore this error.